Error al momento de importar módulos personalizados en python
no se si módulo es la palabra adecuada, pero el caso es que necesito usar un grupo de funciones personalizadas en un fichero que yo creé llamado modulo_de_funciones.ipynb de Google Colab y necesito usarlo en un fichero llamado instalación_de_modulos.ipynb. He utilizado estas instrucciones:
para modulo_de_funciones:
 def absol(x):
   if x<0:
   x=-x
   return x

 def cuadrado(x):
    y=x**2
    return y

para instalacion_de_modulos.ipynb he utilizado este código:
 import os, sys
 from google.colab import drive
 drive.mount('/content/drive')
 nb_path = '/content/notebooks'
 os.symlink('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks', nb_path)
 sys.path.insert(0,nb_path)

pero al compilar este codigo siguiente me sale error:
 !pip install --target=$nb_path modulo_de_funciones

y este es el error:
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement modulo_de_funciones (from 
 versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for modulo_de_funciones

mi pregunta es, porque? porque Google Colab no identifica este módulo? No entiendo esto.
Sé que las funciones que voy a usar ya están predefinidas en python, pero yo lo quiero hacer de esta forma, llamando a un fichero para que ejecute en otro programa, si se podría decir así
Agradezco de antemano su pronta respuesta
